# Meteor - get object from Footable with a button in hidden column

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, meteor, footable

I work on meteor with footable. I fill the table with a {{each}}.
I need to set a button in this footable, on a hidden column, like [here](https://fooplugins.github.io/FooTable/docs/examples/basic/hiding-columns.html). In my helper, I want to get corresponding object by writing:

```
'click #updateFilter': function(evt) {
    console.dir(this);
}
```

It works as long as the button is not in a `<td>` tag or if the button is not on a hidden column. The following html code doesn't work, `console.dir(this);`give me something wrong.

```
<table class="table footable table-stripped toggle-arrow-tiny">
    <thead>
    <tr>
             <th>ID</th>
             <th data-hide="all">update</th>                 
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {{#each filters}}
            <tr>
                 <td>{{_id}}</td>
                 <!-- **********Problem is here*********** -->
                 <td>
                      <button id="updateFilter" class="btn btn-w-m btn-primary m-t btn-block">Update</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
       {{/each}}                     
   </tbody>                      
</table>
```

How can I access to my object data in this case?

Comment: Couldn't it be that you use ids in multiple rows? Can you provide some more code and information? Maybe some Meteor Fiddle?

Comment: @Jirik I don"t think it's a multiple ids problem because if `<button [...] />` is outside <td> tags, it works well. Do you know a Fiddle for meteor? meteorPad.com is not online anymore

Comment: I can't find any Meteor fiddle:( maybe someone else could help